# How to automatically run some command after connect in DBeaver?

Tags: authentication, db2-luw, dbeaver

In DBeaver 22.1.2 I created connection to Db2 v11.5.7.0 database with *user1*.

Every time to start working with connection I do:

1. Right click on connection and select **SQL Editor | New SQL script**.
2. Then I need to switch user with command: `set session_user=user2` and then I execute command.
3. Now running SQLs as usual.

How to do above three steps automatically after I open new script window (or after connect)?

What I have tried so far?

- If used right click on connection and **Edit Connection** there is **Connection Settings | Shell Commands**, but it looks like those commands are run in separate process and also I can't figure it out how to run above command in it.

Comment: It seems "shell commands" are exactly that, i.e. not for SQL but for the operating-system shell.  I do not know a way to achieve this  in a simple manner with DBeaver. However, I know that IBM Data Studio supports an optional connection parameter like this "specialRegisters=SESSION_USER=USER2" that lets you assign special registers at connection time. But this won't work with Dbeaver as far as I can tell.

Comment: @mao `specialRegisters=SESSION_USER=USER2;` in jdbc URL (`;` at the end of whatever property setting is necessarily as usual) does work presuming that given user has [SETSESSIONUSER privilege](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-grant-setsessionuser-privilege) on `USER2`.

Comment: @mao It works with my dbeaver 22.0.2 & Db2 11.1.4.4. Just in case: Dbeaver doesn't allow to specify full jdbc URL for Db2 for LUW data sources, and we have to put all necessary properties in the `Database` field in the format like `dbname:property1=value1;...;propertyN=valueN;`.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein, got it, i had put a ; after the dbname instead of :. I will make an answer.

Comment: @folow Newer used DB2 with Dbeaver, but with Postgres, configurable bootstrap queries are in the initialization section in the Connection setting. There you can configure whatever you want to run right after connection establishment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer specifically addresses only setting of the special register SESSION_USER following connection.  For more general SQL to be run after connecting, a different answer is necessary.

Dbeaver 22.1.2 will allow usage of the `specialRegisters` jdbc property, which lets you assign SESSION_USER special register, and any other special registers you might need.

Tested with Dbeaver 22.1.2 on Linux, and Db2-LUW 11.5.7.0 on Linux.

The key detail is that the `specialRegisters` property **cannot** be specified currently on the `Edit Connection` > `Driver Properties` > `Advanced driver properties` screen. If you try to add the setting here, dbeaver will silently discard the setting .

Instead, to get it to work, it's necessary to append to the database-name field  on the `Edit connection` > `Main` screen, a colon and the setting and a semicolon.   For example suppose your database name is sample, then you would use this value in the database field:

`sample:specialRegisters=SESSION_USER=user2;`

This works with Db2-LUW as long as the connecting userid has the SETSESSIONUSER privilege for the target authid (which has to be granted in advance by a suitable user).

Comment: Tested: added specialRegisters in Database field and it works.